# Websocket connection - not receiving message after some time C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, websocket

I built a websocket server in C#. Relevant code is below. The problem is when the `if (result.EndOfMessage)` is called, the websocket stops listening for any more messages. If any message comes later on, then that message isnt recieved from the client.

How can I receive the messages after a while from the client?

```
public async Task Listen(int port)
{
  try
  {
    IPAddress serverAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"); // localhost

    _listener = new TcpListener(serverAddress, port);
    _listener.Start();

    while (true)
    {
      TcpClient tcpClient = await _listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
      await Task.Run(() => 
    ProcessTcpClientAsync(tcpClient).ConfigureAwait(false));
    }
  }
  catch (SocketException ex)
  {
    throw new Exception(message, ex);
  }
}

private async Task<string> ProcessTcpClientAsync(TcpClient tcpClient)
{
  CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();

  try
  {
    if (_isDisposed)
    {
      return string.Empty;
    }

    // get a secure or insecure stream
    NetworkStream stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
    WebSocketHttpContext context = await _webSocketServerFactory.ReadHttpHeaderFromStreamAsync(stream);

    if (context.IsWebSocketRequest)
    {
      WebSocket webSocket = await _webSocketServerFactory.AcceptWebSocketAsync(context);

      await RespondToWebSocketRequestAsync(webSocket, CancellationToken.None);
    }
  }
  catch (ObjectDisposedException ex)
  {
    // do nothing. This will be thrown if the Listener has been stopped
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
  }
}

public async Task RespondToWebSocketRequestAsync(WebSocket webSocket, CancellationToken token)
{
  ArraySegment<byte> buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[BUFFER_SIZE]);

  while (true)
  {
    WebSocketReceiveResult result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, token);

    if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
    {
      break;
    }

    if (result.Count > BUFFER_SIZE)
    {
      await webSocket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.MessageTooBig,
          $"Web socket frame cannot exceed buffer size of {BUFFER_SIZE:#,##0} bytes. Send multiple frames instead.",
          token);
      break;
    }

    if (result.EndOfMessage)
    {
      break;
    }

    // Process data
    SomeMethod();
  }
}
```

Comment: By using all that `catch{}` blocks you hide all exceptions and messages that would tell you what's wrong. That `catch (ObjectDisposedException ex)` is unjustified - *find* and remove the zombie object instead of covering up the problem

Comment: ok, this was for debugging. the exceptions are never caught. i will remove it.

Comment: Your problem is probably that you `break` out of the eternal loop when the message has been received, without starting another async for a new message. Also your `SomeMethod()` will never be executed, since you `break` before it.

Comment: somemethod does get executed.